# Hostel search site that lists prices by type of accommodation selected

Tags: bookings, hostels, hostelworld

I have this problem any time I try to use sites like Hostelworld and Hostelbookers for private rooms or shared rooms of a certain size. When you filter by room type, the prices in the listings are whatever their cheapest room type is ***even if it's not what you filtered for***.

Is there any hostel site similar to Hostelworld, that lets you filter by room type, then changes the prices in the listings to show the cheapest **valid** room for my filter selection?

---

For example, suppose there are three properties where I'm going:

- **Superhostel:** Double: £45 per person, 4-bed private: £25 per person, 16-bed: £10 per person
- **Megahostel:** 4-bed: £21 per person, 16-bed: £12 per person
- **Bob's B&B:** Single: £50 per person, Double: £30 per person

I'm looking for a hostel site where, if I select "Double room", I see a view like this, that tells me clearly what the prices are for the cheapest match to the option(s) I selected:

- Superhostel: **£45**
- Bob's B&B: **£30**

...but sites like Hostelworld give me an unhelpful view like this, which give a misleading impression about which are cheaper and what the normal price range is for what I'm searching for:

- Superhostel: Private from **£25**, dorms from **£10**
- Bob's B&B: Private from **£30**

...or sometimes even like this:

- Superhostel: **£10**
- Bob's B&B: **£30**

---

Here's a real-life example, I'm looking for a cheap single room for a meeting, I've selected "one person" and "single room", and the top listing is this, which looks impossibly cheap:

[image]

...and it is: that "£11 private" is not anything even close to my criteria, unless I always travel with seven clones:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Hostelz.com](http://www.hostelz.com/hostels/England/London) is an aggregator of hostel booking sites (including Hostelworld) that does this.

Hostelz calculate private rooms correctly and show the price for booking the cheapest private room(s) that meet(s) the minimum number of beds you need (if you want a double, select two beds - they'll highlight the price for a triple or octuple only if booking out the whole room is cheaper).

[image: Hostelz price per room]

Versus here's how Hostelworld shows the same thing:
[image: hostelworld comparison 1/2]
[image: hostelworld comparison 2/2]

Comment: Looks like what I want! I've tried it and got a couple of odd results (e.g. one place was listed as £59 on hostelz but went down to £39 when I clicked through to Hostelworld - I'm not complaining, just slightly puzzled!) - I'll accept once I've figured out why this sometimes happens!

Comment: (I work for Hostelz.com). Thanks to Carl for suggesting the site. user568458, please send us specifics about where you saw that price difference and we'll see if there's an issue we need to fix. Also, after reading the original question I think it would be even better if we add a way to filter searches by specific room type (double, twin, etc.). I think we can add that feature.  Give me a few hours.

Comment: @traveld wow, what a great response! Thanks! The specific place I had weird results with was Belgravia Rooms in London, UK (Victoria area), searching for single rooms for one night. I got different prices and, on some dates, different room types and availability between Hostelz and then clicking through to Hostelworld. Don't know why. Other properties seem fine (but I only tried a couple)

Comment: Ok, the Room Type filter feature is now live so you can now search cities by specific room types (and see the prices for just those types). About price difference issue, I couldn't reproduce the problem, other than it might be confusing because Hostelworld displays prices per person instead of per room (so a 3 person room is shown as 1/3 the price... even if you did a search for a room for one person). If it isn't that, please send us specifics on the dates you were searching with the contact form on our site and we'll get it figured out.